# Memory leak when using NSString inside for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 100 images in my resource bundle named like image1.jpg,image2.jpg.
Basically what i am trying to do is create path names to those images dynamically inside a for loop.
While testing in simulator,the images loaded fine and the app did not crash.But while testing the app with instruments i was shocked to see the heavy memory leak that was happening while i was creating the path1 object.

```
     I am pasting  the entire method here for reference

- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {             

    self.arrayImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];      

    for(int i=1 ; i<100 ; i++){            

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Century%d",i];
        NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"jpg"];            
        [self.arrayImages addObject:path1];        
    }                        
}
return self;
```

}

As i have not made use of any alloc inside the loop i dont have any ownership and hence no right to release the object.What is the reason for this memory leak??

Kindly explain the problem and provide the necessary solution in order to fix it..

As always,any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: where did you see the leaks ? in Instruments ?

Comment: yes.. i found the leaks in instruments

Answer (score 3):

`arrayImages` is retaining `path1`, and so if you do not release `arrayImages` it will leak. How are you creating `arrayImages`, and are you releasing it anywhere?

Edited based on comments:

Make sure you release `arrayImages` in your `-dealloc` method like so: `[arrayImages release];` (note the lack of `self`).

Comment: I am adding arrayImages to the autorelease pool by calling the autorelease method when i allocate it

Comment: @Mr.Anonymous I am agree with @jrtc27. Show us how do you declare `arrayImages` and how do you initialise it and release.

Comment: But how is the `@property` defined?

Comment: @Nekto i have copied the hole method...- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {             
        self.arrayImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];      
        for(int i=1 ; i<100 ; i++){            
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Century%d",i];
            NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"jpg"];            
            [self.arrayImages addObject:path1];
        }                        
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: @jrtc27  @property(nonatomic,retain)

Comment: But in your .h file you have declared `imagesArray` as an `@property`. Can you please paste that code?

Comment: And are you releasing `imagesArray` in your `-dealloc` method?

Comment: i am not releasing it as i have used  the autorelease method

Comment: Common misconception. You autorelease when you alloc/init (either do taht or release it manually), but as the property is defined as `retain`, you also need to release it in your `-dealloc` method.

Comment: @jrtc27 tried ur approach also but no luck.. m still experiencing the memory leak while creating the path1 object

Comment: Busy at the moment - give me 2-3 hours and I'll have another look.

Comment: Just tested the code you have posted and no leaks occur. What are you doing with `arrayImages`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no leak in the code you've shown.

There are (at least) two possibilities:

1. You have a leak in code you didn't paste into your question
2. Everything is fine and Instruments gave you a false-positive

Your loop *will* create a lot of autoreleased variables. These won't be deallocated until after the loop has finished, but that's how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the leak would be this line right here:

```cpp
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Century%d",i];
```

By using convenience methods in Objective-C, what happens in the background is the following:

```cpp
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Century%d", i] autorelease];
```

Not using alloc/init to create a weak reference is a misconception. You are always the owner of a created object, no matter how you create it. The convenience method simply does the alloc/init and autoreleases it for you.

Here's what I would suggest you do to avoid leaking memory:

```cpp
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {             

        self.arrayImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

        NSAutoreleasePool *tmpPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        for(int i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i++) {

            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Century%d",i];
            NSString *path1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"jpg"]];
            [self.arrayImages addObject:path1];
            [path1 release];
        }

        [tmpPool drain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Let me know if this works better for you.

-EDIT- Allocating the path1 object and releasing it after adding to arrayImages.

Comment: Hey sgermain06 tried the approach u suggested.. still experiencing the same memory leak while creating path1 object

Comment: The voodoo you suggest makes no difference with regard to memory leaks. It just keeps the high watermark lower at the expense of `NSAutoreleasePool` performance overhead. This may help in certain optimization scenarios, but won't fix any memory leaks (there aren't any in the OP, by the way).